# To use ImageAlpha and ImageOptim to compress PNGs?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have an iPhone app which I'm converting to a universal iPhone / iPad app. With that, there are many more pngs that I'm adding for the artwork of the iPad version. This inflates my binary size to about 90 mb which is way too big.

I'm thinking about using ImageAlpha and ImageOptim to reduce the size of my pngs, but I'm wondering, are there any draw backs? It almost seems too good to be true. In testing, it's knocking down the size of some of my pngs by 70%! Most of the pngs are heavily texturized illustrations that I use for the backgrounds / menus in my app.

Can anyone see any reason not to use ImageAlpha and ImageOptim in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is depend on your need.

ImageOptim use different 5 tool to compress your PNG image without compromise with quality . With ImageAlpha you can do your manual work. With ImageAlpha u will get more compression but it is manual and time consuming task. So the best answer is try both for 5 10 image and see how much difference u get and decide based on your need.

Have a look here : [Case study: Tweetbot for iPad](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html)

If one are using this image compression method than Don't forgoth to read this : [Xcode's built-in (de)optimization](http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html)

Other Reference Related to image:

[Avoiding Image Decompression Sickness](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/)
[iPhone 5 Image Decompression Benchmarked](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/09/iphone-5-image-decompression-benchmarked/)

Comment: Also nice to read:  http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/ and http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/09/iphone-5-image-decompression-benchmarked/ PNG arn't always the way to go ;)

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks to improve answer.

Comment: In my cause, using ImageAlpha and ImageOptim had no effect on the quality of my images, so it was a no brainer. Cut about 400 mb off the images I have in my server and was able to keep my binary size to 27 mb when I added the iPad artwork and converted the iPhone artwork (it had been 28 mb initially).